# Self-hosting nextjs

Tags: jss, nextjs

I couldn't find any information online how this can be done with sitecore.

All documentation talk about hosting it on third-party providers such as Vercel or Netfliy.

But it says next js can be hosted on anything that supports node js.

If i want to deploy my infrastructure on VMs (on-premise) only:

1. How the infrastructure will look like ?
2. I believe we will need CM but do we still need CDs or just nodes server ?
3. How SSG / ISR will work ?

I am new to next js, previously with react we used to have CM, CDs and Node servers for SSR but not sure how this setup will work with next js.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/20/sitecore-headless-development/deployment-options-for-jss-next-js-apps.html) official document links for Deployment options for JSS Next.js apps.

**Node.js Server**

Next.js JSS apps can be deployed to any hosting provider or environment that supports Node.js. For more information refer to the following resources:

1. [Next.js documentation on Node.js Server deployment.](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#nodejs-server)
2. [A discussion on Next.js and Docker.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16995)

Also, refer to [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploy-sitecore-headless-nextjjs-app-azure-web-ivan-buzyka) article that explains how to Deploy Sitecore Headless Nextj.js app to Azure Web App.

Hope it helps!